# error C2227: left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Tags: c++-cli

when i press F5 to start application, i get c2227 error
i don't  know how to fix it,------------------------------------------------------------------------
output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: YM! Download Manager, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  YM! Download Manager.cpp
1>c:\users\youssef\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ym! download manager\ym! download manager\Form1.h(289): error C2227: left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>c:\users\youssef\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ym! download manager\ym! download manager\Form1.h(290): error C2227: left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>c:\users\youssef\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ym! download manager\ym! download manager\Form1.h(291): error C2227: left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>c:\users\youssef\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ym! download manager\ym! download manager\Form1.h(292): error C2227: left of '->Value' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`
```

Codes:
**Form1.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace YMDownloadManager {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Net;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox^  groupBox1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox^  groupBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar^  progress;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  bytesrecieved;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  totalbytesrecieved;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  percent;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
            this->groupBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->groupBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox());
            this->percent = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->bytesrecieved = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->totalbytesrecieved = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->progress = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar());
            this->label6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->groupBox1->SuspendLayout();
            this->groupBox2->SuspendLayout();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // groupBox1
            // 
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->groupBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
            this->groupBox1->Name = L"groupBox1";
            this->groupBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(299, 124);
            this->groupBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->groupBox1->TabStop = false;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Franklin Gothic Medium", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(268, 54);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 20);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 7;
            this->button2->Text = L"...";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Courier New", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(110, 95);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 6;
            this->button1->Text = L"Download";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(63, 54);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(205, 20);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(39, 25);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(253, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Courier New", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(5, 57);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(63, 14);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label2->Text = L"Save To:";
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Courier New", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(8, 28);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 14);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label1->Text = L"URL:";
            // 
            // groupBox2
            // 
            this->groupBox2->Controls->Add(this->percent);
            this->groupBox2->Controls->Add(this->bytesrecieved);
            this->groupBox2->Controls->Add(this->totalbytesrecieved);
            this->groupBox2->Controls->Add(this->progress);
            this->groupBox2->Controls->Add(this->label6);
            this->groupBox2->Controls->Add(this->label5);
            this->groupBox2->Controls->Add(this->label4);
            this->groupBox2->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->groupBox2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Courier New", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->groupBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 152);
            this->groupBox2->Name = L"groupBox2";
            this->groupBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(299, 100);
            this->groupBox2->TabIndex = 0;
            this->groupBox2->TabStop = false;
            this->groupBox2->Text = L"Status";
            // 
            // percent
            // 
            this->percent->AutoSize = true;
            this->percent->Location = System::Drawing::Point(117, 11);
            this->percent->Name = L"percent";
            this->percent->Size = System::Drawing::Size(49, 14);
            this->percent->TabIndex = 7;
            this->percent->Text = L"label7";
            // 
            // bytesrecieved
            // 
            this->bytesrecieved->AutoSize = true;
            this->bytesrecieved->Location = System::Drawing::Point(127, 29);
            this->bytesrecieved->Name = L"bytesrecieved";
            this->bytesrecieved->Size = System::Drawing::Size(0, 14);
            this->bytesrecieved->TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // totalbytesrecieved
            // 
            this->totalbytesrecieved->AutoSize = true;
            this->totalbytesrecieved->Location = System::Drawing::Point(106, 55);
            this->totalbytesrecieved->Name = L"totalbytesrecieved";
            this->totalbytesrecieved->Size = System::Drawing::Size(0, 14);
            this->totalbytesrecieved->TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // progress
            // 
            this->progress->Location = System::Drawing::Point(6, 73);
            this->progress->Name = L"progress";
            this->progress->Size = System::Drawing::Size(287, 19);
            this->progress->TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this->label6->AutoSize = true;
            this->label6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(243, 55);
            this->label6->Name = L"label6";
            this->label6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(56, 14);
            this->label6->TabIndex = 3;
            this->label6->Text = L"Byte(s)";
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this->label5->AutoSize = true;
            this->label5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(8, 55);
            this->label5->Name = L"label5";
            this->label5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(91, 14);
            this->label5->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label5->Text = L"Total Bytes:";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this->label4->AutoSize = true;
            this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(243, 29);
            this->label4->Name = L"label4";
            this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(56, 14);
            this->label4->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label4->Text = L"Byte(s)";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(8, 29);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(112, 14);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label3->Text = L"Bytes Recieved:";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(323, 264);
            this->Controls->Add(this->groupBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->groupBox1);
            this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedSingle;
            this->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^  >(resources->GetObject(L"$this.Icon")));
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"YM! Download Manager";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->groupBox1->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->groupBox1->PerformLayout();
            this->groupBox2->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->groupBox2->PerformLayout();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                  WebClient^ client = gcnew WebClient();
             client->DownloadProgressChanged += gcnew DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressChanged);
             client->DownloadFileCompleted +=  gcnew AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadComplete);
             client->DownloadFileAsync(gcnew Uri(textBox1->Text), textBox2->Text);
             }
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
              bytesrecieved->BringToFront();
             totalbytesrecieved->BringToFront();
             progress->BringToFront();
             percent->BringToFront();
             bytesrecieved->Text = L"......................................";
             totalbytesrecieved->Text = L".................................";
             percent->Text = L"... %";
         }
         static void DownloadProgressChanged(System::Object^ sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs^ e)
         {
             bytesrecieved->Text = e->BytesReceived.ToString();
             totalbytesrecieved->Text = e->TotalBytesToReceive.ToString();
             percent->Text = e->ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " %";
             progress->Value = e->ProgressPercentage;
         }
          static void DownloadComplete(System::Object^ sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs^ e)
         {
             MessageBox::Show("Download Has Completed Successfully!", "Message From Program", 
                 MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
         }
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             SaveFileDialog^ save = gcnew SaveFileDialog();
                 save->Title = "Choose A Location For The Download To Save To.";
                 if (save->ShowDialog() == Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
                 {
                     textBox2->Text = save->FileName;
                 }
             }
};
}
```

any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Instead of pasting all of your code, reduce to the least amount of code that still represents your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handlers are declared as `static` for some reason.  This means, like all static member functions, that they can't use non-static members unqualified.  So the names `bytesrecieved`, `totalbytesrecieved`, etc (which are spelled wrong btw) cannot be used.

You almost always want non-static member functions for event handlers.

Instead of

```
client->DownloadProgressChanged += gcnew DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressChanged);
```

you need

```
client->DownloadProgressChanged += gcnew DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(this, &Form1::DownloadProgressChanged);
```

and remove the `static` keyword from the declaration of `DownloadProgressChanged`